# Transfer object parameters between controllers

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have two methods inside a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/feed")
public class FeedbackController extends BaseAccountController {

@RequestMapping("/reply")
        public ModelAndView ReplyMsg(FeedBack temp,ModelMap modelMap,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        ................   
        FeedBack fb = new FeedBack();
        fb.setProductId(temp.getProductId());
        view.setViewName("redirect:/feed/list.do");
        view.addObject("feedback",fb);
        return view;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/list")
        public String list(FeedBack feedback, ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ......
    Integer productId = feedback.getProductId();//check if feedback object is transferred successfully
    return "/feedback/list"; // the .jsp or .ftl file.
    }

}
```

FeedBack is a very simple java bean.I want to transfer this object from ReplyMsg() to list().

But the result is:
Yes,the functioin was forwarded to list(), but the feedback.getProductId().it means that the list() doesn't get the FeedBack object from ReplyMsg();

After I change view.setViewName("redirect:/feed/list.do"); to view.setViewName("forward:/feed/list.do"); , it also doesn't work.

So , anyone could tell me what can I do? I am just new for java front end;

Comment: That isn't how the web work... What is it you want to achieve with the passing? The method should ideally read it again from the database.

Comment: How does this method know the query condition?What I want to achieve is just pass this FeedBack Object from ReplyMsg() to list().

Comment: No you want/need to pass a id. The web knowns nothing about your objects it knows about strings.

Comment: This is a lot of things you are trying to do, just put a bean to the session scope.

Comment: Put a bean to the session scope?Would you please give me a example?